# Yii: weird redirect behaviour (https -> http)

Tags: php, yii

I have a whole website working using HTTPS protocol. But recently I have noticed very weird bahaviour of Yii. When I make a redirect:

```
$this->redirect('/article/123456');
```

It first does 302-redirect to *http* version of the page (I can see by headers):

```
HTTP://site.xyz/article/123456
```

> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45-0+deb7u2

Then NGINX does a 301-redirect to the *https* version:

```
HTTPS://site.xyz/article/123456
```

Why is it happening and how does Yii build an absolute URL (always thought it uses relative ones)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/**
     * Redirects the browser to the specified URL.
     * @param string $url URL to be redirected to. Note that when URL is not
     * absolute (not starting with "/") it will be relative to current request URL.
     * @param boolean $terminate whether to terminate the current application
     * @param integer $statusCode the HTTP status code. Defaults to 302. See {@link http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html}
     * for details about HTTP status code.
     */
public function redirect($url,$terminate=true,$statusCode=302)
    {
        if(strpos($url,'/')===0 && strpos($url,'//')!==0)
            $url=$this->getHostInfo().$url;
        header('Location: '.$url, true, $statusCode);
        if($terminate)
            Yii::app()->end();
    }
```

[Source](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/04f97932ddfbf9c5bdaae0a6a41b851544704a27/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L885)

Check the note regarding the URL parameter:

> @param string $url URL to be redirected to. **Note that when URL is not
>        * absolute (not starting with "/") it will be relative to current request URL.**

However, In your code the URL is starting with "/" so according to the source code, the next thing that would happen is: $url = $this->getHostInfo().$url;

So let's take a look at the source of the getHostInfo function:

```
public function getHostInfo($schema='')
    {
        if($this->_hostInfo===null)
        {
            if($secure=$this->getIsSecureConnection())
                $http='https';
            else
                $http='http';
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))
                $this->_hostInfo=$http.'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
            else
            {
                $this->_hostInfo=$http.'://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
                $port=$secure ? $this->getSecurePort() : $this->getPort();
                if(($port!==80 && !$secure) || ($port!==443 && $secure))
                    $this->_hostInfo.=':'.$port;
            }
        }
        if($schema!=='')
        {
            $secure=$this->getIsSecureConnection();
            if($secure && $schema==='https' || !$secure && $schema==='http')
                return $this->_hostInfo;
            $port=$schema==='https' ? $this->getSecurePort() : $this->getPort();
            if($port!==80 && $schema==='http' || $port!==443 && $schema==='https')
                $port=':'.$port;
            else
                $port='';
            $pos=strpos($this->_hostInfo,':');
            return $schema.substr($this->_hostInfo,$pos,strcspn($this->_hostInfo,':',$pos+1)+1).$port;
        }
        else
            return $this->_hostInfo;
    }
```

I'd advise you to check if the first condition returns true (while I don't find it likely that _hostInfo has been defined) and to check the result of the $this->getIsSecureConnection() function.

Comment: Thanks, I have found the issue. Server is not setting $_SERVER['HTTPS'] (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.17/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L581) and it's causing this behaviour. As a workaround I am setting it manually in *index.php* and looking for a more permanent solution meanwhile.

Comment: Well... it's a more rare situation but if you'd follow the next step, it would be to check the getIsSecureConnection function (https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/04f97932ddfbf9c5bdaae0a6a41b851544704a27/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L581) So you would have come to the same conclusion eventually. Good luck.